# Type and Definition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

[image: Question]

Above is a question I am having problems with. It asks me to give a type and define a non infix function.

So my approach was to use pattern matching.

The idea was to take two booleans, then go through patterns

```
 xor :: bool -> bool -> bool
 xor True True == False
 xor True False == True
 xor False True == True
 xor False False == False
```

I am getting a compile error.

```
Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here and how I can fix it?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

please consider reading a basic haskell tutorial - like [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Types are written with captial cases and the `==` operator is not assignment but tests for equality

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor True True = False
xor True False = True
xor False True = True
xor False False = False
```

also note that this can be simplified to

```
xor x y = x /= y
```

after all it is just checking wether the two values you pass in are not the same.

or even more

```
xor = (/=)
```

this style is called point-free, which means if the type signature is clear no parameters are needed (sometimes parameters are referred to as points, for historical/mathematical reasons).

By the way if you wonder what `TemplateHaskell` is - it is a compiler extension of GHC, which allows you to write code that at compile time creates haskell code - which then is type-checked and compiled again - I think about it as type-safe meta-programming.